# exclude some methods in @BeforeMethod in TestNG

Tags: unit-testing, testng

I would like to call mehtods in my testing before they actually happen

```
@BeforeMethod
public void setUpMethod() throws Exception {
}
```

EXCEPT for a given test method

for example, I want to test delete() before it is applied sysmetaically at the beginning of the test methods

I would like thus to make something like:

```
@BeforeMethod("all methods except delete()")
public void setUpMethod() throws Exception {
    delete();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way can be to put delete() in a group say 
@Test(group="excludeBef")

Now in your testng xml, setup two tests, one in which you just include this group, in which case it won't run the beforeMethod for this group and a separate test which excludes this group

```
<test verbose="2" name="Default test" >
<groups>
    <run>
      <include name="excludeBef"></include>
        </run>
</groups>
<classes..go  here>
</test>
<test>
  <groups> - exclude the group </group>
  <classes ..go here>
```